# How to re-assign number values to a character array efficiently in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, character

Okie dokie, this is my first time posting here, so forgive me if my formatting isn't great. 
I'm currently in my second C++ class and our assignment was to create a tic tac toe game using a 1D array. The way that our professor wanted it required the array to use characters rather than just integers.
I have my code for the game working, but I want to be able to play a new game after someone has won or tied. In order to do this, I need to get rid of the X's and O's that are now stored in my array. 
My trouble is trying to create a loop to re-assign the character values appropriately.

I'm totally new to the concept of arrays, and my understanding is definitely still fragile to say the least. If I'm just totally missing something that would simplify this, please help me out! 
Currently it just prints out random ascii characters because it doesn't know that the numbers are supposed to be interpreted as characters. Any ideas? :)

Update: I found a brute force way of re-assigning the values, but it just looks like there's gotta be a better way.

```
// This is the initial board setup

char theBoard[SIZE] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};

// It is re-assigned values of 'X's and 'O's throughout the game
// By the end it looks more like : {X, O, X, O, O, X, X, X} if you can imagine

// My brute force method looks like this: 
void initializeBoard(char theBoard[], int SIZE)
{
    theBoard[0] = '0';
    theBoard[1] = '1';
    theBoard[2] = '2';
    theBoard[3] = '3';
    theBoard[4] = '4';
    theBoard[5] = '5';
    theBoard[6] = '6';
    theBoard[7] = '7';
    theBoard[8] = '8';
}

// And the for loop I was trying to use looked like this: 

void initializeBoard(char theBoard[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            theBoard[i] = i;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you describe your problem as "trying to create a loop to re-assign the character values appropriately", then why did you fill your question with a large program, 99% of which does not have anything to do with the loop in question? The problem with this question isn't the "formatting isn't great", but that it fails to meet the "minimal" requirement of a [mre].

Comment: Hi Sam, I just received an email from Stack Overflow with their recommendations for postings. I quickly realized I put way too much code here. I just updated it so *hopefully* this is more direct and minimal. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, `0` and `'0'` are two different things. One is an integer value 0, and one is an integer value 48, which happens to be the same as the ASCII code for the character '0'.

The loop that you are trying to write is, simply:

```
void initializeBoard(char theBoard[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            theBoard[i] = '0' + i;
        }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you could also use `std::iota()`